# Datagrid combobox disappearing content + autocomplete

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, datatemplate

I've been trying to solve this problem since yesterday but without any success (googling). I have a combobox in a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and when I select something and then click another cell, the content of combobox disappears, but when clicked again in stays. When scrolling down the datagrid, the  situation is similar.

I've tried almost everything what I've found on the net but without any success. I do not understand why it happens.

When I switch to a `DataGridComboboxColumn`, everything works well, but I cannot implement a searchable (autocomplete) combobox in this situation.

My combobox in xaml looks like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfCars}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay}"               
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox
                    Width="150"
                    IsEditable="True"
                    IsDropDownOpen="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TypeLists}}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="Type"
                    SelectedValuePath="IDType"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType}"                              
                    SelectedValue="{Binding IDType, 
                                            Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    IsReadOnly="False"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
                </ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid>
```

`SelectedCar` is of type `Car`, `ListOfCars` is of type `List<Car>`
`SelectedValue` (`IDType`) is a property in the `Car` class.

I would like to achieve 2 things:

1. When selected, an item in the combobox stays even though I click on other cell.
2. Is there any easy way to implement autocomplete combobox? (I tried with `DotNetKit.Wpf.AutoCompleteComboBox` but outside datagrid it works like a charm but inside situation is the same as with combobox...)

Comment: The datacontext of your cell template is Car (class of Car) so this class must include the property SelectedType to work. Is it like that?

Comment: Car class contains IDType and SelectedValue is bound to this property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding first question, I replicated your case, I did a few changes. It works fine for me (Win10 VS pro 2019 .Net 4.7.2). Hopefully you find your answer somewhere there.

I created your classes

```
public class Car
{
    public int IDType { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int IDType { get; set; }

}
```

I created a view model with some samples

```
class ViewModel
{
    public List<Car> ListOfCars { get; set; }
    public Car SelectedCar { get; set; }
    public List<Type> TypeLists { get; set; }


    public ViewModel()
    {
        // Add five cars
        ListOfCars = new List<Car>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ListOfCars.Add(new Car());
        }

        // Add three types: type0, type1, type2
        TypeLists = new List<Type>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            TypeLists.Add(new Type() { Name = $"type{i}", IDType = i });
        }
    }
}
```

For View, I used main window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

I added datagrid in Main Window XAML with some changes to go with my view model. If using UserControl, in the code below change AncestorType to UserControl.

```
<DataGrid 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfCars}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox
                            Width="150"
                            IsEditable="True"
                            IsDropDownOpen="False"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding 
                                Path = DataContext.TypeLists, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorType=Window}}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                            SelectedValuePath="IDType"                                                           
                            SelectedValue="{Binding IDType, 
                                        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                            IsReadOnly="False"
                            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I get below table, left column is comboxes bound to TypeLists, right column is Car IDType auto generated.

[image]

I changed some combo boxes and then scrolled, everything in place.
[image]

Based on experience data disappears from window/usercontrol for two reasons: wrong binding and null injection into properties.

When wrong binding, data is not stored and any refresh of window they will be gone. In debug mode check the output window of VS, it gives you information if there is corrupt bindings.

Sometimes a null is injected into a property when navigating pages. This can be avoided by adding the line below in the setter of problematic properties:

```
if (value==null) return
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I cannot replicate this because the ``ItemsSource="{Binding 
                                Path = DataContext.TypeLists, 
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorType=Window}}"``doesn't work in my case. I need to replace it using ```ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TypeLists}}"```. Maybe because I use IoC container and ServiceLocator to instanciate DataContext within xaml file. Could you please write if combobox values dissappeares when you scroll datagrid? Thanks

Comment: It works like a charm. I have one more question: when I validate row using DataAnnotations and IDataErrorInfo I need to click on any other cell first, otherwise when selecting sth from combobox and then clicking on other cell, comobobox content disappear. How to solve it?